# ACL based on VLAN

Tags: vlan, acl, hp

I am trying to learn ACL on hp 2530.
When I use : 
**sh access-list** command the following is displayed:

```
ACL-NAME-STR          Show detailed information for an ACL.
 config                Show all configured ACLs on the switch with the CLI
                       syntax used to create them.
 ports                 Show ACLs applied to the specified ports.
 radius                Show ACLs applied via RADIUS.
 resources             Show ACL resource usage and availability.
 vlan                  Show ACLs applied to the specified VLAN.
```

I have no idea how to configure vlan based ACL.
Someone please Help.

Comment: please specify which device it is, unfortunately HP reuse the same number for different model line. Could be an Aruba 2530 switch or a Procurve 2530 switch for example, and I think there's also some 2530 in their router line.

Comment: As far as I know the Aruba 2530 and the HPE 2530 are identical except for the case.

Comment: Sorry its Aruba 2530 J9776A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you define the rule, e.g. deny 192.168.1.1 DNS access anywhere, permit everything else:

`ip access-list extended "rulename"
10 deny udp 192.168.1.1/32 any eq 53 log
9999 permit ip any any
exit`

Then you apply the rule to the VLAN 99:

`vlan 99 ip access-group "rulename"`

Edit: There's an implicit last entry `deny ip any any` that will drop all remaining traffic in the VLAN if not explicitly overridden. Since you're still familiarizing yourself with ACLs I wanted to make a point of this.

Comment: `9999 permit ip any any` i don't understand the 9999, what is that in relation to the other commands?

Comment: rules are applied in order .... 10 is the first, 9999 just a convention for "last rule",

Comment: Room to insert more rules later.